# How to serialize slice of fixed length data structure in Go

Tags: go

The following code generates **panic: binary.Write: invalid type main.test**:

```
type (
    config struct {
        Key uint16
        Val uint16
    }
    test struct {
        Mode uint32
        Data []config
    }
)

func main() {
    t := test{
        Mode: 5,
        Data: []config{
            {1, 2},
            {3, 4},
        },
    }
    var bs bytes.Buffer
    assert(binary.Write(&bs, binary.LittleEndian, t))
}
```

The key point is:

1. length of the `config` data structure is fixed, but the `test` structure contains a slice of `config`, whose number varies.
2. I need to interact with other program written in C, so cannot use things like GOB.

Is there anyway to binary-encode such data structure, apart from do it manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not writing out a slice, as slices are supported. Quoting from [`binary.Write()`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/binary#Write):

> Write writes the binary representation of data into w. Data must be a fixed-size value or a **slice of fixed-size values**, or a pointer to such data.

The problem is that the size of `config` is not fixed. It is not fixed because it contains a field of slice type, and the binary representation of the slice is not fixed (depends on its length).

So writing a slice value is supported, writing a value of composite type (e.g. struct) holding a slice is not supported for the above mentioned reason.

You may change the field to an array type (e.g. `[2]config`) but I assume this isn't sufficient to you.

You may write the fields using [`encoding/binary`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/binary) *individually*, in which case you *can* write a slice value.

For example:

```
var bs bytes.Buffer
fmt.Println(binary.Write(&bs, binary.LittleEndian, t.Mode))
fmt.Println(binary.Write(&bs, binary.LittleEndian, t.Data))
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/mkWZDz-Ci_J)):

```
<nil>
<nil>
```

There was a proposal to extend `encoding/binary` to support similar cases (see [here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/29222)), but was rejected. `encoding/binary` is for simple things.

If you need more flexibility, use [`encoding/gob`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/gob) (although Go specific), or use [`encoding/json`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json) (supported by all languages).

Comment: Your proposed method is exactly what I am doing now. The idea of using array instead of slice is acceptable, only if it can deal with "short" data.  i.e., I have a maximum allowed number of elements, say, 8. But if the data is short than 8 items, it will generate ErrUnexpectedEOF, and the struct is **not** filled at all.

Comment: btw, json is not acceptable either, the C program I am interacting with is a low level communication program dealing with binary data only.

Comment: @xrfang As detailed in the answer, you can't write a value of `test` using `binary.Write()`, it doesn't matter if that's what you need. You may use another library or do it manually (or use a different representation).